# Asset() en un controller en Symfony2.3

Tags: php, symfony2

A una imagen en el "src" le tengo que poner una varibale path, cuando hago eso en el twig, la url resultante es invalida, lo cual me lleva a usar asset() para que sea correcta, pero no funciona porque dice que esa variable con el path no existe.

Lo que ahora quiero hacer es usar la misma funcion de asset() pero en el controller, asi la url resultante correcta en el controller enviar al html.twig

Es de esta manera como envio el path, en un json y con jquery le agrego el atributo src a la imagen

```
$path=$promocion->getImagen()->getEnlace()['path'];
$detallesdeproductos[0]["path"]=$path;
$response = new Response(json_encode($detallesdeproductos));
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
return $response;
```

Comment: Pero el "path" al que te refieres es una ruta relativa a tu aplicacion???

Comment: Es una ruta relativa a la imagen